# How to convert dual alternating language audio clips to text using Python?

Tags: python, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I am trying to convert some dual language audio clips to text. The clips start with English and then language changes to Deutsch and again it changes to English.

Below is my code:

```
import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer()
audio_file = sr.AudioFile('path_to_audio')

with audio_file as source:
    audio_file_record = r.record(source)

print(r.recognize_google(audio_file_record, language='en-US'))
print(r.recognize_google(audio_file_record, language='de-DE'))
```

Problem is first print statement only prints the English audio part before the Deutsch and does not print English after the Deutsch.

How to get complete clip conversion with full text of both the languages?

I know i can set `offset` and `duration` to reach to specific part of a clip but then the solution will be specific to a clip which i do not want.

Comment: Can you get a timestamp for the start & end of the translated segment? If so, you could use that to parse the file in chunks.

Comment: @SiHa, thanks for the idea. Not seen capturing timestamp as part of speech_recognition. Will try with timestamp before and after recognize_google call to see if it ends after first converted segment or waits till complete clip duration.

Comment: Hi were you able to solve the issue. I am doing a similar project and have a similar audio. Will you tell how you were able to solve it.